# Selecting nested list values Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to use nested lists as so:

| A | B | [C1, C2, C3] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * | * | [*1, *2, *3] |
| * | * | [*1, *2, *3] |

where a data table is created with lists, and then a specific column has a list as it's cell value. I want to be able to store this table in this format, but request data so that only a specific index of these cells are called to new tables like so:

| A | B | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * | * | *1 |
| * | * | *1 |

and

| A | B | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * | * | *2 |
| * | * | *2 |

and

| A | B | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * | * | *3 |
| * | * | *3 |

Currently I run the following code to create the new tables:

```
dataset1 = []
dataset2 = []
dataset3 = []
for row in self.data:
    datarow1 = []
    datarow2 = []
    datarow3 = []
    for col in row:
        if len(col) > 1 and isinstance(col, str) is False:
            datarow1.append(col[0])
            datarow2.append(col[1])
            datarow3.append(col[2])
        else:
            datarow1.append(col)
            datarow2.append(col)
            datarow3.append(col)
    dataset1.append(datarow1[:])
    dataset2.append(datarow2[:])
    dataset3.append(datarow3[:])
```

Which runs fine, but I am wondering if there is a way to build the table in such a way that I can call the values without this block of code to separate them

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking

Comment: Could you provide a sample value of `self.data`?  I'm pretty sure this can be done in a simple nested comprehension but I can't test the code without sample input.

Comment: @Samwise sure, a valid self.data sample would be:
 `data = [['A','B',['Ca','Cb','Cc'],['Da','Db','Dc']],['11','12',['13a','13b','13c'],['14a','14b','14c']],['21','22',['23a','23b','23c'],['24a','24b','24c']],['31','32',['33a','33b','33c'],['34a','34b','34c']]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the three datasets in a simple comprehension rather than building intermediate lists and appending them:

```
datasets = [[[
    col[i] if len(col) and not isinstance(col, str) else col 
    for col in row
] for row in data] for i in range(3)]
```

If you need to do anything else that involves all three datasets it's probably easier to have them in a list than in three named variables, but if you do need to extract `dataset1`, `dataset2`, and `dataset3` individually, that's simply:

```
[dataset1, dataset2, dataset3] = datasets
```